# Is there a way to merge two for loops using Streams in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists in which one is of type String and the other is of some entity object. How to iterate through those two lists or compare it by using java 8

```
List<Admin> admin= new ArrayList<>();

for (Admin ah : subProducers) {
    for (String value : values) {
        if (ah.getFirstName().contains(value) || ah.getLastName().contains(value)) {
            admin.add(ah);
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently using the for loop to verify that condition, I don't find any better way to combine it using java 8 streams.

Comment: You are adding one admin object multiple times to the list?

Comment: An interesting exercise, mostly because it’s apparent that the code you already have is clearer than any use of Streams.

Comment: @VGR I don’t get the people who try to “improve” perfectly expressed pieces eventually turning them into difficult-to-follow-and-maintain stream ***t :)

Comment: Is it intentional that this code may add the same `Admin` to the target list multiple times?

Comment: @holger NO,  we should not add same Admin object to the target list, It should be different

Comment: But that’s what your code does. If `values` is `[ "John", "Smith" ]`, an `Admin` with first name `"John"` and last name `"Smith"` will be added two times. When `values` is `[ "J", "o", "h", "n" ]`, the same `Admin` will be added even four times.

Comment: @holger No, It adds only one Admin. Even if we give something like your case, It takes only one admin

Comment: @JeevaD just *try* it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like an `anyMatch` with nested streams :

```
subProducers.stream()
            .filter(a -> values.stream()
                               .anyMatch(b -> a.getFirstName().contains(b)
                                           || a.getLastName().contains(b)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
```